# Warum ist es "du kannst dir nicht vorstellen" und nicht "du kannst dich nicht vorstellen"?

Tags: grammatical-case, dative, accusative, reflexive

Even though the reflexive verb is *sich vorstellen*? And how can one differentiate and use the cases properly for reflexive verbs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Those are two very different meanings of the verb *vorstellen*.

1. **sich**[*reflexive, dat*] **etwas**[*acc*] **vorstellen** - *to imagine/picture something*; This use always requires **both** a dative reflexive pronoun **and** an accusative object.

> Ich stelle **mir**[*reflexive, dat*] **einen rosa Elefanten**[*acc*] vor. - *I am imagining a pink elephant.*
>
> Du kannst **dir**[*reflexive, dat*] nicht vorstellen, **wie es ist ein Elefant zu sein**[*complement as accusative object*]. - *You can't imagine what it's like being an elephant*.

2. (**jemandem**[dat]) **jemanden/etwas**[*acc*] **vorstellen** - *to introduce someone/something (to someone)*; This use only requires an accusative object.

> Ich stelle **dir**[*dat*] **einen rosa Elefanten**[*acc*] vor. - *I am introducing you to a pink elephant*.
>
> Du kannst **dich**[*reflexive, acc*] nicht vorstellen. - *You can't introduce yourself*.

Comment: Super!!! Danke :)